# Cannot Compile scip with IPOPT=true

Tags: scip, ipopt

I have downloaded ipopt and compiled it(I dont have libipopt.a, but I have libipopt.so and libipopt.la). When I try to compile scip with IPOPT=true, I get the error message:
 fatal error: IpoptConfig.h: No such file or directory

I have already added the soft links. I don't know if it has anything to do with me not having libipopt.a?

Answer (score 2):

After doing make install in Ipopt, you should have a directory include in the Ipopt build directory (or in the "prefix"-directory if you used --prefix) which should contain a file coin/IpoptConfig.h. Please check.

Comment: Hi Stefan,yes I do have that file.seems like scip can't find it

Comment: I didn't create a build folder to launch configure , I ran ./configure in the Ipopt root directory. Don't know if that matters

Comment: does this have anything to do with my Ipopt version?I used the newest Ipopt-3.12.4

Comment: Try building SCIP with VERBOSE=true as well. That should show you what include-path flag (-I) will be passed to the compiler, i.e., in which directory the SCIP buildsystem expects to find the Ipopt headers.
When SCIP's make asked for the Ipopt installation directory, you should have given it your Ipopt root directory (as that's where you did configure, make, make install). So SCIP expects the Ipopt headers in <Ipopt-root-directory>/include/coin.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  For me the problem was that in an older version of SCIP ipopt should be linked at `scip/lib` and in the newer version it is `scip/lib/static`.